# Does the latest release May 2008 of .NET enterprise library have the updater app block?

Tags: enterprise-library

Does the latest version of the enterprise library (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512464.aspx) come with the updater application block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it doesn't:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc511823.aspx

It's now in the 'Archived Application Blocks' section of the MSDN docs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc485231.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No. Microsoft considers the Updater Application Block to be replaced by ClickOnce in .NET 2.0. The Enterprise Library for .NET 1.1 is no longer updated.